# ASP.NET MVC3 Multilingual webpage Javascripts not working on changing culture name

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, multilingual

In my multilingual website, Javascripts in all the pages are not working when i am changing the culture name in the web.config file. (using `<globalization culture="" uiCulture=""/>`)
The javascript is not working for the below mentioned cultures

1. be-by{Belarus)
2. ro-ro(Romania)
3. bg-bg(Bulgaria)
4. sv-se(Sweden)
5. th-th(Thailand)
6. lv-lv(Latvia)

Whereas it works for spanish cultures (like es-mx,es-pa),english cultures and a few other cultures(like hu-hu(hungary))
Javascript in my website is used for popup windows and asynchronous call for cascading dropdowns.

Its noteworthy that i am using culture specific resource files for translating the website into their specific languages.

EDIT:
Jquery pop up code -

`$("#dialog").dialog("open");`

```
 $("#Product_BookingEndDate").val($("#Product_BookingEndDate").val().split(' ')[0]);
    $("#Product_BookingStartDate").val($("#Product_BookingStartDate").val().split(' ')[0]);
    $("#Product_StartDate").val($("#Product_StartDate").val().split(' ')[0]);
    $("#Product_EndDate").val($("#Product_EndDate").val().split(' ')[0]);
```

this opens pop up window and removes the time portion from datetime value in en-us culture but not in above mentioned cultures. Culture settings are specified in web.config, e.g

```
<globalization culture="tr-tr" uiCulture="tr-tr"/>
```

Comment: what do you mean by javascript not working?

Comment: The popup window controls are getting displayed at the bottom of the page and cascading dropdown list are not fetching data on selection change

Comment: I have also faced similar issues sometimes back but couldn't find any solution yet :(

Comment: Your question still has very vew details. You should describe how the mentioned culture codes are connected to your javascript code, what you try to achieve, what should happen and what happens instead. Code examples could be of great help.

Comment: @suknic--> pls see the edited portion

Comment: Question: if you look at the response headers in firebug or chrome, what is the charset value? Note: I'm not referring to a meta tag for content-type / charset that you might be setting in the <head> section. I'm referring to what is set by (I think) IIS based on the current culture code of the request. Another question, if you tried this with tradition Chinese (ch-ZHT I think), do you have the same issue?